# Determine moment and shear stress door

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, stresses, strength, moments

Determine shear stress and moment of bolt:

- Internal Height of Door = 198.2 cm
- Internal Width of Door = 89.9 cm
- Thickness Door = 3.9 cm
- Weight Door = 45.76 kg or448.9 N
- Elasticity = 9.8 GPa or N/mm<sup>2</sup>
- Area = 18818.18 cm<sup>2</sup>
- Distance between two plat = 84.4 cm
- Number of hinge = 3
- Number of bolt per hinge = 1
- Bolt = 4 mm
- Number of bolts = 8
- Length of the bolt = 10.5 cm

external Height of door(from bottom to top)=203.6 cm